# Issues with serving audio files through MVC3 | Using Various HTML5 Players

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, audio

I've recently encountered an issue that I seem unable to solve. I am creating a simple component for an application that plays audio files (*primarily .mp3 and .wav*) and after doing some testing, the application appears to work fine in Chrome.

However in IE9, which is the only major browser that I am concerned with I seem to hit a brick wall when serving my audio files.

The files are currently being requested through a Controller Action as shown:

```
public ActionResult PlayAudioFile(string id)
{     
    AudioFile af = FileAgent.GetAudioFile(id);

    try
    {
          //Grabs the file via a Provider
          Stream resultStream = StorageProvider[af.Provider].ReadFile(af.Location);
          resultStream.Position = 0;

          //Added several headers in attempts to resolve the issues
          Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=audio.mp3");
          Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", resultStream.Length.ToString());
          Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
          Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
          Response.AddHeader("Content-Range","bytes 0-" + (resultStream.Length-1).ToString() + "/" + resultStream.Length.ToString());

          //Returns the file and associated file type (from the Provider)
          return new FileStreamResult(resultStream, resultStream.ContentType);
     }
     catch
     {
            //Uh oh. Error
     }         
}
```

The above works great for Chrome and has worked in a variety of HTML5 Players, such as **[jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/)**, **[audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/)** and [**MediaElement**](http://mediaelementjs.com/). However, when the file is requested by something like the following *(using jPlayer syntax)*:

```
$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
    mp3: '@Url.Action("PlayAudioFile","Home")?id=D00023',
});
```

*or audio.js syntax*:

```
player.load('@Url.Action("PlayAudioFile","Home")?id=D00023');
```

*and associated audio.js audio tag:*

```
<audio preload="auto" crossorigin="use-credentials"></audio>
```

Which fires the proper action and returns the FileStreamResult, however it appears that all of the players are having difficulty deciphering the file and reading it properly. I have tried several players and have run into this same issue in all of them.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcome. Thanks.

**NOTES:**

- As mentioned in one of the comments, I have attempted using multiple and a variety of comment types to resolve this issue. None of which have worked.
- When exploring some possible root causes of this issue, I noticed that removing the [Authorize] attribute cleared up some of the issues with directly accessing the file, but all of the players were unable to load the file within IE9.
- I am now convinced that this could be a credentials issue and that when I need to request the file through jPlayer or audio.js (or what have you) I need to include the necessary credentials to allow it to access the file through the controller.
- Attempted to use `$.ajax({ withCredentials: true})` and `<audio crossorigin='use-credentials>`. Both without success.

**HEADER INFORMATION:**

Both of the requests (the working one in Chrome and the non-functional one in IE9) both have these same headers:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600, s-maxage=0
Date: [Current Date Time]
Expires: [Current Date Time + max-age]
Vary: *

Content-Length: 77870
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Last-Modified: [Date]

Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-77869/77870
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

Comment: What is your final HTML output (on this `mp3: '@Url.Action("PlayAudioFile","Home")?id=D00023'`
)?

Comment: The URL is correct (/Home/PlayAudioFile?id=D00023). Navigating directly to the action will open the associated audio file within the browser and when applying that same URL into one of the audio players it will load it as you would expect (such that it could be played, seeked through etc.) However, it only appears to function in Chrome, as IE9 fails to load the file.

Comment: Like @Hoff said, you could try adding the extension in your controller name, PlayAudioFile.mp3 (`/Home/PlayAudioFile.mp3?id=D00023`) . Even if isn't possible to name a controller like that, you could use a custom routing. But it's just a guess.

Comment: Did you register mimetypes on IIS? Could be a css question like z-index? Does it works in IE9 with mode: 'shim'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After delving further into the issue, it became apparent that the issue was being caused by the encoding of the .mp3 files themselves during the recording process. I elected to process them through Audacity and after doing so they were recognized by IE9 (as well as other browsers).

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Don't serve audio as `application/octet-stream` (which indicates only generic content) but as either `audio/mp3`, `audio/wave` or [some other appropriate contentType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements) that matches the audio that you're serving.

Comment: Agreed - I'd inspect the extension and output the appropriate content type.

Comment: Thanks Spender. I have tried this, as well as numerous other content types such as "audio/wav", "audio/mpeg" as well as type them based on the content. This failed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension to the end after the id, for example: `'@Url.Action("PlayAudioFile","Home")?id=D00023&ext=.mp3'` or `'@Url.Action("PlayAudioFile","Home")?id=D00023&ext=mp3'`?

Comment: @Hoff, I've tried adding those and those attempt didn't' work as well. I made an update to the Notes section of the question. I believe that this issue is concerning credentials and accessing the file. (I could easily be wrong, but its the track I am currently pursuing.)

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to look at what is being returned from the server? Make sure the content type is actually being set correctly.

Comment: I've looked at them through both the Developer Tools in IE and the tools in Chrome as well. The headers are basically the same between the two of them, with the exception that Chrome works and IE9 does not. I'll check in Fiddler though.

Comment: After looking through with Fiddler, both appear to have the same Response Headers. I have posted the information from there.

Comment: Updated the question and attached a bounty. If anyone would like some additional information, please let me know.

Comment: Granting you the bounty as yours was really the only other answer. I resolved the issue by realizing it was an issue with the audio recording / encoding process as to why it failed to play. Enjoy the bounty. :)